# Why CSS variables are not inherited in pseudo elements?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I have found something a bit strange, and could not find anything in the CSS custom properties spec about that. Here is a simple example: https://codepen.io/bakura10/pen/RwxNPxz

```css
:root {
  --background: red;
}

.test {
  position: relative;
}

.test::before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: var(--background);
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  TEST
</div>
```

As you can see, despite the variable --background being defined at the root scope, it is simply not accessible from the before or after pseudo element.

Why is that so?

Answer (score 1):

No it's working, you should give your `:before` `position:absolute` (it didn't have any width or height).

```css
:root {
  --background: red;
}

.test {
  position: relative;
/*   background: var(--background); */
}

.test::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
/*   background-color: red; */
  background: var(--background);
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  TEST
</div>
```

Comment: My bad, I actually had the same in my example. Actually I got confused because of the Chrome developer tool, which reports the variable as "not defined" (even in your example). I think this is a bug of Chrome inspector, which confused me thinking it was not working. I will report that to Blink developers !

Comment: Found a bug reported about that. For those who would stumble into the same issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1174553&q=css%20variables%20not%20defined&can=2

Comment: @MichaelGallego your latest here comment could be an answer to your own question. Not a fix, but the reason why the vars don't show up. ;)